# Why does a parent class method doesn't pass the argument when calling another parent method while the child class has methods with identical names?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, arguments

I encountered the following. I have a parent class and a child class with 2-2 identically named methods **a** and **b**. Method **a** in the parent expects an additional argument which is passed to it by the other parent method, **b**. However when trying to access the parameter in the invoked **a** method it is *undefined*.

If I change the name of method **a** either in parent or the child I get the result I expected and the argument is passed.

I also understand that both the parents' and the child's **a** method is invoked. I do not understand however why wasn't the argument passed regardless. I'm also wondering if there is any other way to avoid this behaviour than renaming the methods?

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {}

  a(param1, param2) {
    console.log('a in parent invoked')
    console.log(param2)
  }

  b(param1) {

    const param2 = 2
    this.a(param1, param2)
  }
}

class TestChild extends Test {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }

  a(param1) {
    console.log('a in child invoked')
    return super.a(param1)

  }

  b(param1) {
    return super.b(param1)
  }
}

const test = new TestChild()
test.b(1)
```

Comment: `TestChild` method `a` calls `Test` method `a` with one parameter ... `super.a(param1)` - where did you think `param2` would come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Test.prototype.b` calls `this.a(…)` with two parameters, which **resolves to the overridden** `TestChild.prototype.a` when called on a child instance. The `TestChild.prototype.a` method calls `super.a(param1)`, neglecting to pass through the second parameter. This is a violation of the subclass contract, as it doesn't implement the same interface as the parent method, and calls the parent method with insufficient arguments.

If you change it to

```
class TestChild extends Test {
  a(param1, ...args) {
    console.log('a in child invoked')
    return super.a(param1, ...args)
  }
}
```

it will work as expected. (Or better yet, just spell out the `param2` explicitly - I'm not sure why you'd want the subclass to have one parameter less in the first place). Maybe

```
class TestChild extends Test {
  a(param1, param2 = 'default') {
    console.log('a in child invoked')
    return super.a(param1, param2)
  }
}
```

then both `test.b(1)` as well as `test.a(1)` will work.

Comment: Thank you! So I could call Test.prototype.a explicitly in Test.b and that would also resolve my issue. But as far as I understand sublcass methods should implement the same interface as the parents'. Got it!

Comment: Indeed, `Test.prototype.a.call(this, param1, param2)` would also work, but that's not what you usually want for methods that can be overridden.